# Thread-local Database Transactions in Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, knex.js

When interfacing with my database I would like to have access to a previously initialized thread-local transaction so that I don't have to pass around my database session. Ideally every API call is wrapped by transaction handling that would start, commit and abort the transaction as needed. Then when database interfacing the transaction could be retrieved by a managing module.

It is my understanding that thread-local behavior is not easily achieved in JS as its execution is effectively single threaded. Is there any way that I can achieve this result such that separate API calls do not see each others transactions and only the one initialized in their codepath? Is my only option to use node worker threads?

Using Express, Node, Knex

Here is an attempt at the transaction handler I made with AsyncLocalStorage, however all API requests were using the same instance of AsyncLocalStorage when testing.

```
import db from '@db-config/db';
import { Knex } from 'knex';
import { AsyncLocalStorage } from 'node:async_hooks';

const asyncLocalStorage : AsyncLocalStorage<any> = new AsyncLocalStorage();
const store = new Map

async function startTransaction(): Promise<void> {
  const transaction = await db.transaction();
  asyncLocalStorage.run(store, () => {
    asyncLocalStorage.getStore().set("txn", transaction);
  })
}

function txn(): Knex.Transaction {
  asyncLocalStorage.enterWith(store);
  const transaction = asyncLocalStorage.getStore().get("txn");

  if (!transaction) {
    throw new Error("Requesting transaction before initialized. " +
      "Please make sure startTransaction is called first.");
  }

  return transaction;
}

function commitTransaction(): void {
  txn().commit();
}

export { startTransaction, txn, commitTransaction }
```